# send SIGINT to child process

Tags: c++, linux, signals, sigint

I am trying to create a child process and then send SIGINT to the child without terminating the parent. I tried this:

```
pid=fork();
  if (!pid)
  {
      setpgrp();
      cout<<"waiting...\n";
      while(1);
  }
  else
      {
      cout<<"parent";
      wait(NULL);
      }
```

but when I hit C-c both process were terminated

Comment: Instead of `while(1);` use `while(1) sleep(1);`   Much easier on the CPU.

Comment: In general, instead of `while(e);` do instead `while(e) continue;`, but in this case **what wallyk said**.

Comment: DigitalRoss: How is using continue different here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try implementing a SIGINT signal handler which, if a child process is running, kills the child process (and if not, shuts down the application).

Alternatively, set the parent's SIGINT handler to SIG_IGN and the child's to SIG_DFL.

Comment: I used `sigaction` to change the signal handler for the parent and it worked, but when tried to set the parent to SIG_IGN and the child to SIG_DFL both child and parent ignored the signal.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use <kbd>CTRL-C</kbd>, this sends a signal to all processes with the same controlling terminal (ie, in the same session). That's something that `setpgid` doesn't change though I think there's a `setsid` (set session ID) call for that purpose.

The easiest solution is simply to target the specific process rather than a session. From the command line:

```
kill -INT pid
```

From C:

```
kill (pid, SIGINT);
```

where pid is the process ID you want to send the signal to.

The parent can get the relevant PID from the return value from `fork()`. If a child wants its own PID, it can call `getpid()`.

Answer (score 5):

Aha, the mystery of process groups and sessions and process group leaders and session group leaders appears again.

Your control/C sent the signal to a group. You need to signal an individual pid, so follow paxdiablo's instructions or signal ("kill") the child from the parent. And don't busy wait! Put a sleep(1) in the loop, or better yet, one of the wait(2) system calls.